# Function annotation for subclasses of abstract class

Tags: python, python-3.x, annotations, type-hinting

I'm trying to use function annotations in the hope that my editor will be better at refactoring. I however am stumbling over the following problem:

I have an abstract base class Algorithm.

```
class Algorithm(metaclass=ABCMeta):
     def __init__(self):   
          self.foo = 'bar'
```

I also have a function that uses instances of subclasses of Algorithm

```
def get_foo(foo_algorithm):
    return foo_algoritm.foo
```

the input foo_algorithm can be an instance of any of the subclasses of Algorithm. How do I sensibly annotate this input? I'm looking for something along the lines off:

```
def get_foo(foo_algorithm: subclassof(Algorithm)):
    return foo_algoritm.foo
```

But I couldn't find the right way to do this.

Comment: Your question is slightly unclear. You are talking as if your `get_foo` would accept a *subclass* of `Algorithm`, rather than an *instance* of a subclass of `Algorithm`. Your code says otherwise; `.foo` is set in the `__init__` method so must be an instance attribute. It wouldn't be present on a class object.

Comment: Good point, edited. It are indeed the instantiated subclasses which I am using.

Comment: Well, I have you covered either way now.

Comment: Thanks you solved my problem, I guess python is always simpler than I think it is :).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just use `Algorithm` directly:

```
def get_foo(foo_algorithm: Algorithm):
    return foo_algoritm.foo
```

and automatically any instance of a subclass will be acceptable (`isinstance(foo_algorithm, Algorithm)` must be true, which applies to all subclasses of a baseclass).

If you can only accept **classes**, then use `Type[Algorithm]` as the type hint:

```
def get_foo(foo_algorithm: Type[Algorithm]):
    return foo_algoritm().foo
```

See the [*The type of class objects* section](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#the-type-of-class-objects) of PEP 484 -- *Type Hints*:

> Sometimes you want to talk about class objects, in particular class objects that inherit from a given class. This can be spelled as `Type[C]` where `C` is a class. To clarify: while `C` (when used as an annotation) refers to instances of class `C`, `Type[C]` refers to subclasses of `C`.

Here I *called* the class object, since `.foo` is an instance attribute according to your code example; a class derived from `Algorithm` would not have such an attribute itself.

Comment: I think `foo_algorithm: Type[Algorithm]` should be `foo_algorithm: Callable[[], Algorithm]` because abstract classes don't specify the parameters of the constructor of their subclasses.

Comment: @umitu `Type[…]` says nothing about what arguments the type constructor accepts. Your `Callable[…]` signature explicitly states that no arguments are acceptable. Many type checkers can validate the arguments anyway as `Type[]` carries more information; you can’t use a `Callable[]` in an `isinstance()` call for example.