# Python type annotations for instance of class derived from abstract base class

Tags: python, python-typing, abstract-base-class

Assume that an abstract base class `MembershipClass` has been created.  Multiple classes are derived from the abstract base class, e.g., `FirstClass`, `SecondClass`, etc.

I wish to use type annotations in a function that accepts as an argument any class derived from `MembershipClass`.  If there are a small number of derived classes (say 2), this should work:

```
from typing import Union
def MyFunc(membership_obj: Union[FirstClass, SecondClass]) -> None:
   ...
```

Is there a way to create a type hint for `membership_obj` which essentially says that its type is any class derived from `MembershipClass` without having to specify each possible derived class in the type annotation?

I have seen two possible solutions:

1. [TypeVar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41790843/python-3-type-annotations-and-subclasses):

```
from typing import TypeVar
BaseType = TypeVar('BaseType', bound=MembershipClass)
def MyFunc(membership_obj: BaseType) -> None:
   ...
```

2. [Direct use of ABC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38791739/function-annotation-for-subclasses-of-abstract-class)

```
def MyFunc(membership_obj: MembershipClass) -> None:
   ...
```

Is either approach acceptable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like both solutions will work, although the mypy messages are slightly different. Consider the following example (I've added mypy errors inline):

```py
from abc import ABC
from typing import TypeVar


class Base(ABC):
    pass


class Sub(Base):
    pass


BaseType = TypeVar("BaseType", bound=Base)


def MyFunc(c: Base) -> None:
    pass


def MyFunc2(c: BaseType) -> None:
    pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    b = Base()
    s = Sub()

    MyFunc(b)
    MyFunc(s)
    MyFunc(3)  # main.py:30: error: Argument 1 to "MyFunc" has incompatible type "int"; expected "Base"

    MyFunc2(b)
    MyFunc2(s)
    MyFunc2(3) # main.py:34: error: Value of type variable "BaseType" of "MyFunc2" cannot be "int"
```

That being said, I think the second method is more readable and intuitive. I think that `TypeVar` is more suited for [generics](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#generics) (that's not to say you shouldn't use it if you want to).